# Symfony2 Form "collection" + Doctrine Column "array" = Empty form_widget

Tags: arrays, symfony, doctrine-orm, entity, symfony-forms

I have a simple question about Symfony2's form type "collection" in combination with doctrine's column "array".**

My Entity:

```
/**
 * @Column(type="array", nullable=true)
 * @var array
 */
private $specifications;
```

My "Main" Form:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('specifications', 'collection', array (
            'type' => new ProductSpecificationType(),
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'by_reference' => false
        )
    );
}
```

My "ProductSpecificationsType" Form:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('group', 'text')
        ->add('info', 'text')
    ;
}
```

And my output with button (twig):

```
{{ form_row(form.specifications) }}
<a data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.specifications.vars.prototype) | e }}" href="#" onclick="return false;">Add</a>
```

The real outout is this (html):

```
<a data-prototype="" href="#" onclick="return false;">Add</a>
```

And the same if I use only the form_widget without the "e" like "escape" at the end.

After save the entity is saved with the array column = null.

So, if I add these lines per FireBug manually to the html form

```
<input type="text" name="product[specifications][0][group]" value="Exam">
<input type="text" name="product[specifications][0][info]" value="ple">
<input type="text" name="product[specifications][1][group]" value="Extra">
<input type="text" name="product[specifications][1][info]" value="Example">
```

and press then "Save", the entity is saved in this format:

```
a:2:{i:0;a:2:{s:5:"group";s:4:"Exam";s:4:"info";s:3:"ple";}i:1;a:2:{s:5:"group";s:5:"Extra";s:4:"info";s:7:"Example";}}
```

My questions:

1. Why is my prototype empty?
2. Why is the form_widget empty? (is also empty if I fill the data above manually!)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: try var_dumping your 'main' form_builder and see what is there. (e.g. var_dump($builder);die;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding 'prototype' => true to the "Main" form builder?
Something like:

```
$builder->add('specifications', 'collection', array (
        'type' => new ProductSpecificationType(),
        'allow_add' => true,
        'allow_delete' => true,
        'by_reference' => false,
        'prototype' => true
    )
);
```